# ("ID").Value not working in ASP.net user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have textbox like below in ASP.net ascx page

```
<input type="text" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txt_OTP" />
```

I want to get textbox input value in jquery (in same ascx page)
but .value or .text function is not available

jquery code:

```
document.getElementById('OTPvalidation1_txt_OTP').Value
```

Here ID is correct but `.Value` or `.text` function is not available in `ascx` page.
Is there any alternative keyword for this in `ascx` page????

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use the static name in javascript/jquery function.

you can use

```
document.getElementById("<%= txt_OTP.ClientID %>")
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('OTPvalidation1_txt_OTP')
```

in any case, if your textbox id will change than javascript will not give you any error.

and now to get the value you can use

```
document.getElementById("<%= txt_OTP.ClientID %>").value;
```

you have used `document.getElementById('OTPvalidation1_txt_OTP').Value`

for javascript to get the value of the input it should be .value not .Value

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes i have tried giving ID in both ways. And also tried value and Value. In aspx page i am getting .value option in jquery code. But for ascx page i am not getting .value option

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.value` instead of `.Value`.
Also are you sure `txt_OTP`'s id is as you mentioned ? usually in webforms I use:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="200" runat="server" id="txt_OTP" ClientIdMode="Static" />
```

Or as others mentioned  in their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use (It's not jQuery Code, It is javascript)

```
document.getElementById('<%= txt_OTP.ClientID %>').value;
```

For jQuery :

```
$('#<%= txt_OTP.ClientID %>').val();
```

Comment: The jQuery option of this answer should be accepted here